# Is there a way to move memory between two areas in a single memory block in Vulkan?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm looking for a command to do the equivalent of

```
void * memmove ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

within a Vulkan memory block. I see lots of bits about copying from one buffer to another but none about this case. Of course all aligned and sizes appropriate.

It is what is needed to lets say remove a chunk of data and then move the lower part up or the upper part down the be contiguous with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that you're referring to the distinction between `memcpy` and `memmove`. Namely, that `memcpy` doesn't work if the destination range is part of the source range, but `memmove` does work with such a range.

All of Vulkan's copy commands require the ranges to be disjoint. Indeed, while `vkCmdCopyBuffer` allows you to specify multiple memory ranges, all of the source ranges need to be disjoint with all of the destination ranges.

So you have two options. You could issue multiple copy commands, with each command being on a disjoint range. However, this requires hard synchronization between each command.

The more reasonable alternative is to copy the data to some scratch memory and then copy it to its final destination. That too requires synchronization, but you only need one such instance of synchronization. If you're doing a lot of these, you can copy all of them to that scratch memory, synchronize, and then copy them all to their destinations.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.  This would be what is needed for things like a memory compactor or defragger or an image cropper etc.  If one could let's say move a chunk down by a gap within a buffer then just loop through all the chunks and when there is a gap move the (contiguous) one above to it down without the need for a temporary.

Comment: @peterk: "*without the need for a temporary*" What makes you think the hardware can do that? I mean, have you looked at the implementation of `memmove`? And that's on a fairly synchronous device like the CPU. The point being that this probably isn't a hardware-based operation. Instead, it has to be manufactured.

Comment: Well hardware has registers like min alloc size aligned and I assume firmware has the ability to loop - but if not implemented or impractical in the API we use what we get 

Comment: @peterk: The DMA engine would still have to wait for each iteration of the loop to fully complete and clear any necessary caches before starting the next one. As it currently stands, you can improve performance if you have a number of memmove operations that you can break into pieces and interleave, such that you have fewer total points of synchronization.